# How can i redirect /dev/tty into file

Tags: tar, archive, progress

I want tar command to show progress somehow in the output as I am working with large files and to have some idea what is the status.
but I can't use some of the popular tools like pv, because only default programs are allowed on the system.

So in tar documentation, I found this option:

```
--checkpoint-action=ttyout='%T\r'
```

and while this outputs the progress in terminal quite nicely, I want to store progress in file in case terminal gets disconnected. But tar in this case, since it uses ttyout, seems to direct its output in /dev/tty.

So my question is, is there a way to redirect /dev/tty into file? and without some fancy programs, but just default tools included in standard linux distributions.

Or another option is with echo

```
--checkpoint-action='echo=\a %T'
```

but that does not have the \r option to output just single line and overwrite it. At least I was not able to make it work with this syntax to modify echo into echo -ne.

So maybe you have some thoughts on this direction

Answer (score 2):

It seems like this should work:

```
tar -cvf archive.tar * | tee filename.log
```

Or maybe you want something more like this?

```
tar --checkpoint --checkpoint-action='exec=echo $TAR_CHECKPOINT > filename.log ' --checkpoint-action='ttyout=%u\r' -cf archive.tar *
```